# Cannot target ul in multi level dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, target, submenu

I am creating an HTML Multi-level Dropdown menu.
I want to change the background of the second menu level when I hover over the first menu level.

I am able to change color of first level dropdown items on hover with the first code snipped below

The background colour of the second level in the dropdown I can change with the second code snippet

So I thought that what I want is achieved by just connecting those two snippets with each other.
But connecting both does not work for me. The last code snipped is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
.dropdown-content > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: blue !important;
}

.dropdown-content > ul > li > ul {
    background: white;
}

.dropdown-content > ul > li > a:hover .dropdown-content > ul > li > ul {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would need to see your html code to be sure, but try something like:

```
.dropdown-content > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Here is an excerpt of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/kon9d6ga/5/
Your first approach does not seem to work thank you anyway

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. I have updated the answer which should work now.

Comment: Thats not quite what I was trying to achieve. I want that what gets ret now when you hover over what is blue now...

Comment: Use `background-color`.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement, maybe update the original question as to what exactly you want to do? I am not able to understand what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the adjacent selectors. Below, the plus sign selector `+` in the third style rule waits for an anchor tag to be hovered over, and then finds the adjacent `.dropdown-content` element and highlights its child `ul` element in red:

```css
.dropdown-content>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.dropdown-content>ul>li>ul {
  background: white;
}

.dropdown-content>ul>li>a:hover+.dropdown-content>ul {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is exactly what I want. But why isn't it working in my project? https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/kon9d6ga/7/

Comment: @BB23 probably because you have style rules that are overriding these rules, or because your HTML is slightly different